# Matplotlib with Jupyter Notebook doesnt draw plot but correct axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to draw plots from a working code but plots doesnt appear to be working correctly. It actually draw x and y axises with correct values but actual plotting/graphic doesn't  appear.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')


plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.title("Rewards")
plt.bar(torch.arange(len(rewards_total)), rewards_total, alpha=0.6, color='green')
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.title("Steps / Episode length")
plt.bar(torch.arange(len(steps_total)), steps_total, alpha=0.6, color='red')
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.title("Egreedy value")
plt.bar(torch.arange(len(egreedy_total)), egreedy_total, alpha=0.6, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly the bars are smaller than one pixel and hence not shown. You could add `edgecolor="black"` - but maybe also question if a barplot is the right kind of visual for your data.

Comment: Thanks man this totally worked even though its just very ugly looking graph